# Relation between armature voltage and mechanical power in electrical Engineering

Tags: electrical-engineering, motors, power

I am searching for an effect chain that leads to the mechanical power $P_{mech}$ of a DC motor, starting with the applied armature voltage $U_{A}$. My request also includes all the electrotechnical quantities with cause, effect and linking formula, which are created 'on the way' between $U_{A}$ and $P_{mech}$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Number of windings?

Comment: I don't need calculations just the theoretical aspect

Answer (score 1):

A DC motor is modelled as a *gyrator*, in which the output RPM (a *flow variable*) is proportional to the input voltage (an *effort variable*.)

As always, the input *power* = (flow variable x effort variable) = (current x voltage)
and similarly the output *power* = (torque x RPM)

Mind the units.

Answer (score 0):

Some formulas for you on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brushed_DC_electric_motor#Torque_and_speed_of_a_DC_motor).

Comment: I'm searching for a specific relation between the armature voltage and the mechanical power, which I didn't find on web.

Answer (score 0):

**Mechanical Power:**
$$P_{m} = \omega \ T_m = \frac {9.55 \ T} {n} \ \ (W)$$

$\omega$ = angular velocity in rad/s.

n = speed in rpm.

9.55 = constant to eliminate 2 radians and 60s/min.

**Torque:**
$$T_m = k_b\ I_a\ -\ T_f \ \ (N \cdot m)$$

$k_b$ = torque constant in N•m/A.

$I_a$ = armature current.

$T_f$ = motor friction torque in N•m.

**Armature Circuit KVL:**

$$U_a = I_a\ R_a -\ U_b \ \ (V)$$

$V_a$ = armature voltage.

$I_a$ = armature resistance in Ω.

**Back emf:**

$$U_b = k_e\ \omega \ \ (V)$$

$k_e$ = back emf constant in V•s/rad.